# Matching from a starting delimiter to an end delimiter (Regex/pattern matching)

Tags: regex, gedit

I am trying to match for a certain block of text.
The format of the text I want to match is

```
<pevz:url>https://some.server.com/arbitraryFoo.jpeg</pevz:url>
```

where only `<pevz:url>` and `</pevz:url>` are known.

My naive try was to match with

`<pevz:url>*([0-9a-zA-Z:/._-])<\/pevz:url>`

but that didn't work. I am using gedit to match with the default search and replace (no `advanced-find`).

How can I match for the whole string?

Best regards,
Joe Cocker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
<pevz:url>(.*?)<\/pevz:url>
```

or

```
<pevz:url>([^>]+)<\/pevz:url>
```

---

### [image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rtjn1J/1)